# For php flush - how to disable gzip for specific file?

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have a ajax call to somefile.php . i want the php script to do a simple task and than send back data to the user, and only than do very time consuming tasks. so i need to flush the output after the first simple task. it doesn't work, probably because i have gzip enables.

I definitely don't want to disable gzip across all the vhost, and also not in all the folder where somefile.php is. i just want to disable it for this specific file. is that possible?

EDIT:

this is what i've included in my apache conf:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

this is my php script:

```
<?php
$sucesss = @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);

ob_start();

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    echo 'printing...';
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

it doesn't work. i still see all the output together after 10 seconds.

Comment: If it's your web server that handles the gzip compression, I think you can't disable it via PHP.

Comment: Maybe look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922934/how-to-disable-mod-deflate-in-apache2

Answer (score 11):

This would be the correct solution, but on some setups it might not work. You might have to explicitly disable the compression in the .htaccess file as well. This solution, however, didn't work for me.

```
<?php
header("Content-Encoding: identity");
?>
```

I was looking for a solutions for the same issue. This is what worked for me but unfortunately it seams NOT to be a VALID header.

```
<?
header("Content-Encoding: none");
?>
```

Comment: Here is the `Content-Encoding` specifications: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5

Comment: `header("Content-Encoding: identity");` sounds more correct.

Comment: I am using SimpleHTMLDom for scraping which does the job and more, but unfortunately it is returning compressed data. I have a fix for that but it doesn't fit in the function that I am using. So I tried these tips to prevent the page from sending Gzip data but none of the suggestions here work.

Comment: @e2-e4 I know that `identity` is correct but sometimes you have proxy servers or other configurations that you cannot change that interfere an encode all traffic.

Answer (score 4):

`apache_setenv()` is correct. See the documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php#60530

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
```

Your problem is that you turned on output buffering with [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). Comment that out.

I've learned that `apache_setenv()` is only available with the PHP Apache module. It's not available when using FPM. In that case, you have to use `.htaccess` to turn off GZip. An example is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36212238/148844

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/index - [E=no-gzip:1]
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_no-gzip 1 no-gzip
```

The `-` means NOOP, `E` means set variable, `1` is the value. After redirects, the variables are renamed and prepended with `REDIRECT_`.

If the output is still being buffered, check if you are going through a proxy or cache. See if headers like `Via: 1.1 varnish` or `Via: 1.1 vegur` are present. They will buffer the response also.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in httpd.conf

```
# exclude certain page requests (e.g. for requesting getMyFile.php?action=getFile&id=3 as non-compressed)
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI getMyFile\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Comment: How can you disable it only for certain requests to the same file? e.g.:
`ajax.php?a=list&id=5` -> with compression
`ajax.php?a=download&file=image.png` -> without compression

Comment: @B.Martin Leave the `$` off of the regex and include the request parameter. Like `ajax\.php\?a=download`.