# How do I disable GZip with SetEnvIfNoCase in Apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, setenvif

I want to disable GZip for certain pages. I have this in my `.htaccess`, but it still turns GZip on (`Content-Encoding: gzip`) when visiting `dashboard/index`.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI /dashboard/index no-gzip dont-vary
```

I tried to add `Header set MyHeader %{REQUEST_URI}` to see what the `Request_URI` was, but it gave an Internal Server Error.

I also tried the regex `dashboard/index`, `dashboard/index.*`, `"/dashboard/index"`, etc., and tried `SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI ...`, but GZip was still on.

If I comment `#AddOutputFilterByType`, then GZip is turned off.

I'm using Apache 2.4.16, Yii 2.0.7, PHP. I'm using FPM in production, so `apache_setenv()` is not available.

Comment: I was able to output a header with the request URI using `Header set myHeaderName "%{REQUEST_URI}e"` which produces header `myHeaderName: /project/web/dashboard/index`. GZip is still on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using rewrites to get rid of `index.php` in the URL. Due to the stage at which `SetEnvIf` runs during the request, `index.php` will be part of the `Request_URI` var used (which is distinct from `%{REQUEST_URI}`).

It's nowadays quite common to not use `PATH_INFO` for rewrites, but just plainly rewrite to `index.php`, where code just reads the original `REQUEST_URI` info. In that case, `Request_URI` in `SetEnvIf` will be just "index.php", so you'd need to set a flag env var in a special dummy rewrite for that URL, and reference it later with a `REDIRECT_` prefix (as there is an internal redirect stage on rewrites where mod_rewrite prefixes all existing env vars with `REDIRECT_`):

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/index - [E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_no-gzip 1 no-gzip
```

There is a slightly less verbose way if you rewrite to `PATH_INFO` (so "`/foobar`" turns to "`/index.php/foobar`" using e.g. a `RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1` rule):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI ^/index.php/dashboard/index.*$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

But that seems more brittle since it'll break if you change the `RewriteRule` mechanics.

Comment: Thank you soooo much !! i've been struggling for 16hours+ to understand why the no-gzip and dont-vary were not working in the case of a redirection within a .htaccess (built for symfony and in production environment so the app.php part of URL was missing and an internal redirection occurs). GG !