# how to disable gzip on PHP-FPM for a request

Tags: php, ajax, fpm, php-7.4

how can I disable http request header with PHP-FPM 7.4

```
content-encoding: gzip
```

I tried with putenv() but it's just adding a new entry but not overriding

```
//$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] ="identity";
header("Content-Encoding: identity");
putenv('no-gzip=1');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', '0');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', '-1');
.
.
.
.
.
$length = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $length");
session_write_close();
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using nginx? If so, this might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/438237/turn-off-gzip-for-a-location-in-nginx

Comment: I'm using apache

Answer (score 0):

after trying all things .htacess one work, maybe it may help someone
url: "product/get_products"

```
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI ^/index.php/product/get_products.*$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36212238/12029165