# How to achieve progressive response using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm building a project in PHP which the system sends a `curl` request to another domain for processing a query. Eg. `http://domain.com/process_query?q=abc`. The `process_query` controller executes the query against a set of files and returns the summary results of individual files in the following format.

```
[
    array('filename' => "one.dat", 'summary_counts' => 5),
    array('filename' => "two.dat", 'summary_counts' => 30),
    array('filename' => "three.dat", 'summary_counts' => 4),
    array('filename' => "four.dat", 'summary_counts' => 70),
    array('filename' => "five.dat", 'summary_counts' => 0)
]
```

It is then captures by the system which sent the curl request and renders it on the screen. I wish to do this in a progressive way. Like, as soon as the `process_query` controller completes processing a file, it should be able to `echo` the response [`array('filename' => "one.dat", 'summary_counts' => 5)`] and continue processing the next file. If this is possible, for every response received the system can show a progressive query processing. Can this be achieved using `PHP-curl`. If not what is the best alternative way?

Comment: curl would block while each request is "in flight", so wouldn't `foreach(...) { curl ...; echo done }`-type stuff do what you want?

Comment: @MarcB you want me to send a separate curl request for every file?

Comment: I am doing it by using socket.io and have done it using TCP... both are fast but if you ask me to this in PHP i would not recommend it. 
I say go for node.js > http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There is a library https://github.com/stil/curl-easy Visit this gitHub library and check the documentation on how to implement it!

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: I don't think the original question was about async/parallel curl requests (although that might help improve performance), I think it was about sending progress back to the browser after each step was completed.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably tools like the one Rafique mentioned to help improve performance by running curl requests in parallel, although if your main goal is to send a progress report after each step in the task is run, you can simply `echo` and then `flush()` the response to the browser.

Here is a super simple script that demonstrates the ability to flush content through to the browser part-way through a script:

```
<?php
echo "1\n";
ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(1);
echo "2\n";
ob_flush();
flush();

sleep(1);
echo "3\n";
```

When you access this from command line like `curl test.php` you'll see the numbers appearing 1, 2, 3 one second apart from each other.

You can use this technique combined with AJAX to trigger a long action from your webpage and then display some kind of progress/status update on the page. You'll probably need to hook into the onprogress event ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668339/can-onprogress-functionality-be-added-to-jquery-ajax-by-using-xhrfields)) or you could otherwise trigger it inside an iframe and see the output display progressively (making sure you pad it [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001628/php-flush-not-working-in-chrome)).