# PHP output buffering throwing warnings

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have to output results while PHP script is running:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' - ';
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is working but throwing warnings:

> Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer
>   to delete or flush in ...

How to fix that?

Comment: Think again and choose another way.

Comment: You should only call `ob_end_flush()` once at the end.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop you are ending the buffer. If you want to do that, you should start a new buffer in each loop.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    ob_start();
    echo $i . ' - ';
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is a neater way to use buffering. It is also more performant as you are only using 1 buffer. If you do not need to `flush` on each loop, you could skip the `ob_flush` within the loop and use `ob_end_flush` instead of `ob_end_clean`.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' - ';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks! but if starting a new buffer in each loop will have impact on performance, would it be better to just clean the first and re-use it? and how to do it?

Comment: Why start the buffer multiple times? All he needs is `ob_flush()`

Comment: @FrankerZ I was editing the answer as you wrote your comment :P

Comment: @JimWright this method is not working as it echoes everything at once and not after each loop

Comment: @medk Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001628/php-flush-not-working-in-chrome). Output buffering can be a bit finicky in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`ob_end_flush()` will disable buffering, so future calls to this in your loop will fail. Simply use `ob_flush()`, which clears the buffer but maintains output buffering:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' - ';
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: You don't need to flush after the loop.

Comment: If he had additional code afterwards, or anything else he is going to echo (Such as a final end statement.) It's important to include.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it like that:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i . ' - ';
    flush();
    @ob_flush();
    @ob_end_clean();
    sleep(1);
}
```

It works now.